# aws download all custom time cloud watch logs within mentioned time period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to process kinesis messages from aws lambda and pushing to power bi.

In lambda have logged application specific messages.

What is the problem now?

I am able to see my messages in cloud watch logs but not all. When I apply filter I am getting specific period messages which is good but not all messages of that period. Within the mentioned range Every time I scroll my mouse to get more messages and download till that point.

For Ex: In UI for specified time range if I get 100 messages I am able to download till this point. There is something I can see as "load more" When I click on it I get around 150 messages. **This is very tedious ** to scroll each time and get more messages and download .

Is there any automated way where I could download in single shot for mentioned period on all messages ?

Any help will reduce lots of effort

Answer (score 1):

You can export the logs to an S3 Bucket using the CloudWatch Logs Console or using the AWS CLI. Specifying the begin time, end time and optionally Stream prefix.

First you need to set appropriate permissions.

Export logs using AWS Console
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html

Export logs using AWS CLI
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html